# Apache `host/~username/` opening `/host/directory/`

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have the following:

```
host/~username/
```

sends the browser the page `/home/username/public_html/index.html`. In another directory `/home/username/site_root/` we have the root of a website starting with its own `/home/username/site_root/index.html`.

**How to do this:** I would like that `host/~username/` sends the browser to `/home/username/site_root/index.html`, if possible keeping `host/~username/` as the address in the address bar.

I have never done anything with Apache. Reading some answers it seems that I might be able to do this by adding a file `/home/username/public_html/.htaccess` with certain commands in it. I have tried imitating what they do with lines like

```
RewriteEngine on
Rewriterule  <...>
```

but I haven't managed to produce any result.

I tried to avoid using the word *redirect* because I don't know if that is the name of what I want to do. I don't want it to load some page that then sends the browser to another location.

I saw another thing that is done modifying `httpd.conf` which changes the *root directory* of the Apache server. I don't have access to this file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something simpler like a symlink?

Comment: Yes, right now it is being used with symbolic links. That doesn't seem like the right approach, though.

Comment: It's perfectly fine if you don't have access to the servers configuration and it works.  mod_rewrite shenanigans are the kludge and will complicate things for quite some time.